# AV sync problem while livestreaming with libav

Tags: c++, audio, video, streaming, libav

I am working on a livestream project. Here is what I am doing now with libav.

1. Receive Mpeg-Ts packets (H264/AAC) and demux them
2. Transcode (resize etc.) video and audio on separate threads
3. Buffer audio until a video frame received with same PTS (Audio and video PTS must be close to each other in order to ensure sync since the beginning of stream)
4. Stream audio and video separately to viewer

In this case, video is 25 fps and audio is 48000hz. When I look at the PES PTS values from demuxer, video PTS increases by 3600 every frame and audio PTS increases by 1920 every frame. I know that encoder counts 90000 tick every second.

To keep audio and video sync, I am using a clock value taken from third step and increasing this clock by 3600 every 40 ms. For example, we got PTS value 108000 from third step (where sync provided). This value is now our origin.

Clock counter C++ code below.

```
video_clock = 108000; // origin from third step 

std::thread t([=]() {
    while (in_sync) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(40));
        video_clock += 3600;
    }
});
t.detach();
```

Here is the problem. I am doing same clock thing with audio but stream goes out of sync after 5-10 mins. I think there is a problem with audio clock. Note that, clock counts right so this isn't about performance or CPU.

> Video frames : 90000 / 3600 = 25 frames

> Video sleep interval (1s / frame count) : 1000 / 25 = 40 ms

> Audio frames : 90000 / 1920 = 46.875 frames

> Audio sleep interval (1s / frame count) : 1000 / 46.875 = 21.333 ms

I calculated these values but 21.333 ms sleep is obviously wrong. Audio and video have different sample count per second, naturally, so they will go out of sync eventually. I am missing something here.

How can I count this clock correctly to keep AV sync?

Comment: `std::this_thread::sleep_for` isn't accurate

Comment: Yes but when I log video_clock variable, it seems it is increasing normally. The problem is I can't sleep thread for 21,333... ms, so my solution is totally wrong.

Comment: Generally you don't sleep on the audio side, just feed buffers into the audio player and sleep on the video side until the audio player reaches the time of the video frame

Comment: Got the point, but I am buffering audio and video to check if there are dropped frames. Because the decoder (currently using decklink) loses audio if there is a gap between frames. It is working if I remove clock, but in that case decklink will consume all packets, there will be no buffer anymore to check dropped frames. I am starting to think this is impossible to implement, sadly.